# Sails Js - Sort by association value with blueprint

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, sails.js

Is it possible to sort the results of a model from an association property with sails js blueprint?

e.g.:

```
// Profile:
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        firstName: { type: 'string', required: true },
        lastName: { type: 'string', required: true },
        user: { model: 'user', required: true }
    }
};
// User:
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        email: { type: 'string', required: true }
    }
};
```

Then do something like:
/api/profiles?populate=user&sort=user.email+DESC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible with Sails blueprints.

You should create a new action in your `ProfileController` to do that:

```
findByEmailDesc: function (req, res) {
  Profile
    .find()
    .populate('user')
    .exec(function (err, profiles) {
      if (err) return res.serverError(err);

      return res.ok(_.sortBy(profiles, 'user.email').reverse());
  });
}
```